# Pandas HDF file size differ dramatically between read and write

Tags: python, pandas, hdfstore

I have a HDF5 file test1.h5 which is generated py Pandas df.to_hdf("test1.h5","t") call. The file size is 27M, and only have one key which is a pandas dataframe.

```
s1 = pd.HDFStore("test1.h5")

<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test1.h5
/t            frame        (shape->[999,2161])
```

Most of the dtypes of the dataframe is float32 with one int and string

```
In [21]: s1['/t'].dtypes.value_counts()
Out[21]: 
float32    2156
object        3
float64       1
int64         1
dtype: int64
```

What puzzles me is that if I save the the dataframe again to another HDF5 file test2.h5, it only has 9.7M:

```
s1['/t'].to_hdf("test2.h5","t")
```

What causes the size different between the read and write? Thank you.

Comment: what gives df.dtypes.value_counts() before you save it?

Comment: to compare the original df vs s1['/t']

Comment: I can't be certain but `df.to_hdf('myfile.h5', 'mykey')` appends by default.  `df.to_hdf('myfile.h5', 'mykey', append=False)` to not do that.  You may have repeated the write step several times and thus appended several times.

Comment: @Boud: the dtypes.value_counts() are the same before I save it.